# Command echo on file returns no space error

Tags: echo

script have a query and if returns around 1200 records it is ok, but when it returns more than 1200 records echo fails with no space, space in the server is available.

(1454 rows affected)
if [ `echo "$RESULT" | grep "^Msg" | wc -l` != 0 ]; then --> this is the command

- grep ^Msg
- wc -l
  ./scriptname[169]: no space - this is the error.

any limitation with echo? Please advise.

resolution(1454 rows affected)
if [ `echo "$RESULT" | grep "^Msg" | wc -l` != 0 ]; then

- grep ^Msg
- wc -l
  ./scriptname[169]: no space